# I need vb.net code to get current system time which should be dynamic according to the system time

Tags: vb.net, datetime

For Example :

If I have open the run the application at 5:41 PM

```
    Login_Page.DATE_TIME.Text = TimeOfDay.ToString("h:mm tt")
    Login_Page.DATE_TIME.Text = Format(Date.Now(), "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt")
```

then these type of codes displays 5:41 PM only.

But I want to display the time dynamicly.

I mean, after a minute the system time will be 5:42 PM

But, Here my text box shows 5:41 PM only.

This is my problem.

Comment: You should use a timer and in `Tick` event of `Timer` update the `Text` of `TextBox` with the current time.

Comment: Thank you Reza Aghaei, I got it

Comment: One more doubt in this. While using these Tick event of Timer, I can't step over into my coding.